# Can I have some help understanding this failed answer review?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, late-answers

Well, I've shamefully failed [another Late Answers review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/27067257). Not actually disputing this, since it probably deserved a downvote for its brevity, but want to understand what the correct course of action would have been.

As far as I understand, having reviewed the [guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/1456253), this answer is not a link-only because it can stand as an answer without the link.
In addition, I reviewed the link and it does go to a real site which describes the techniques described in the answer (as far as I can tell).

So I'm left with three explanations:

One, the technique described doesn't actually technically work, as indicated by the single downvote the answer has. I'm not sure I have the technical knowledge to evaluate that. So perhaps I should have **skipped**.

Two, the answer does not directly answer the question, which explicitly asks how to access particular values. While the answer does not directly respond to this question, I believed this to be because the answerer was proposing a different avenue than the one OP was going down, ie, you can try what you're doing, but a better way is to use this additional library, which in my mind would also be a helpful and real answer. Based on this, the proper course was to **flag as not an answer**.

Three, the technique is valid and so is the answer content, but there simply is not enough detail. Based on this, it should have been **downvoted**.

Can you help me understand what I did wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It always pays to tread very carefully when reviewing on the late-answers queue and dealing with answers containing external links.

In this case, you should probably have checked for undisclosed self-promotion.

E.g.:

[image]

Of course, it could be *just a coincidence*. But if you had seen that, you would probably have at least skipped the review out of caution.

Comment: But by clicking on the link, you are literally doing what they want! I saw a spam question where for each website visit, they got 2 dollars in revenue. Perhaps this isn't the same, but in any case, getting a userscript that gives a preview of a link would be handy for reviewing.

Comment: Er... and pray what's the difference between _you_ doing the clicking, and the userscript doing the clicking for you? It's exactly the same thing, as far as I can tell. Please enlighten me if I'm wrong. Would not be the first time. And if one is not willing to check on links when reviewing, one should simply skip reviews with links.

Comment: No, I mean the user script gives a dropdown preview, just so you can see the home page in the site. So if you hover over the link, then you get a small preview.

Comment: Yup, and that preview you get by fetching the content at the other side of the link. Which is exactly the same as clicking, right? How is it not?

Comment: And in any case, you are optimizing for the wrong thing. You are reviewing. You are supposed to check on things. If by reviewing external links one gets spam removed, your lone page-view is worth a thousand page-views avoided for future visitors.

Comment: I have no guarantee that the spam will be deleted immediately, right? I have a spam flag that I raised a month ago, and it just got deleted like 2 days ago. And I have deleted a few link spams by going into the link, only to find it's their personal website. I just try to occasionally let go of these and leave them to someone else.

Comment: If you do not want to review external links, that's fine (although better _skip_ those reviews). But advising other users not to review these links because somehow plays into the spammers hands, it is not fine.

Comment: Good catch. Pretty obvious now that you've shown me. I was looking closely at the content to make sure it had content as advertised and ignored the left hand bar! Since this one is so blatant, I guess it makes a good review!

Comment: I'm not telling anyone else, and let me be clear: I just said **_I_** don't do them. I was just saying what my thinking process was like.

Comment: @10Rep And I think I described why your "userscript does the clicking" thought process was flawed anyway. If you were simply describing a personal thought process in a way where the comment did not apply to my answer, maybe it was not altogether necessary. My impression was that you were saying that clicking those links was problematic, in response to my suggestion to thoroughly check external links.

Comment: @yivi Perhaps my wording was unclear. English is after all my second language, so sorry if I was unclear. I just meant to explain my own thought process. That was truly my intent.